# How to get emacs grep to search based on project root?

Tags: emacs

I want emacs grep to always search from the root project directory, not the directory of the currently opened file. The assumption here is that all of your coding projects are under the same folder (like `~/repositories/`).

I tried to prefix the grep command with a command that `cd`s into the project root, but this leaves the emacs working directory variable untouched, so while the grep is performed in the correct filesystem location, jumping to search results is broken, because the partial file paths of the grep matches are appended to the emacs working directory.

To summarize, I want to be in `~/repositories/my_project/folder1/file1.c`, invoke grep command which will search from `~/repositories/my_project/`, and have the jump to file functionality of the grep buffer work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not answer directly your `grep` question but especially when working with projects, I always find [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) to be a great tool.

Projectile, amongst other things, provides a `grep`, `ack` and `ag` search on a project level which is probably what you are looking for.

E.g.

`C-c p s g` runs `grep` on the files in the project.

Comment: if you could post the command name I would be really grateful

Comment: @Asalle projectile commands easy to find with m+x and then just type "projectile-". It's all starts with that prefix

Answer (score 0):

you can simply run this using `project.el` builtin project package
manager in emacs
`project-execute-extended-command`
with keybinding `C-x p x` and then execute the
extended command `rgrep` or `grep` depending on what you want.

So I normaly do
`C-x p x` -> `rgrep` -> enter-query
et voila!